# Using qXL library to query a table from kdb+ server instance

Tags: database, excel, kdb, vba

Has anyone had experience on using the qXL library to query a table from kdb+ server instance? The [example](https://github.com/exxeleron/qXL/tree/master/doc) provided in Github is for the local kdb+ instance rather querying a server instance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but the example at the bottom of the page you referenced [suggests](https://github.com/exxeleron/qXL/blob/master/doc/RTD-Examples.md#opening-and-closing-the-workbook) that you can specify a host IP as a string:

> =qRtdOpen("testRTDConnection","10.10.4.205",17010)

The [API documentation](https://github.com/exxeleron/qXL/blob/master/doc/RTD-API-Functions.md#qrtdopen) states:

> hostname [String] - name or IP address of the host to which connection should be opened